# Safari vs Chrome touchpad wheel event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I have event listener for "wheel" event which used to zoom in/out of a map. Using touchpad it works well in Chrome on the following cases:

- Scroll (Slide two fingers up or down to scroll)
- Zoom in or out (Pinch with two fingers to zoom in or out)
- Pinch with three fingers

But in Safari it doesn't dispatches "wheel" event in 2nd case:

- Zoom in or out (Pinch with two fingers to zoom in or out)

Instead, browser applies Command + / Command - function which zooms in/out of whole website.

**Questions**

- Is it browser or operation system related feature? According to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895 it's OS related feature but does it means that Chrome works incorrectly if it doesn't supports "Zoom in or out" gesture?
- Should I prevent this behavior in Safari or this is feature
  for user which I shouldn't disable?
- Finally, is it possible to disable this feature (only touchpad feature and not at all) using JavaScript in order to have consistent behavior in all browsers - zoom in/out of the map instead of whole website?

Answer (score 1):

As there are no answers yet, I'm sharing with the conclusion which was accepted on my project:

> In Safari "pinch with two fingers" is reserved for Zoom In/Out of
>   website unlike Chrome/Firefox where this gesture dispatches "wheel"
>   (scrolling) event.
>
> There are other touchpad gestures which designed for "wheel"
>   (scrolling) event and you can use to zoom in/out of the map:
>
> - Slide two fingers up or down to scroll
> - Pinch with three fingers
>
> Behavior on the other websites is the same. Example:
>   http://geojson.io/